# Map one column's distinct values to the count of those values in a chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, count, mapping, aes

I'm trying to create a chart with `x` and `y`.

How can I map one column's distinct values to the count of those values of the same column in a chart.
For example If I have a data like this:

```
column_name
1
1
2
4
1
2
2
3
3
4
2
1
```

I want the mapping to be like this

```
x >> y
1 >> 4
2 >> 4
3 >> 2
4 >> 2
```

I tried using the `table` function to count the number of appearance for each distinct value, it worked but when I put it inside the `aes` function it gives me this error:

```
Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the `ggplot2` package, you do not need to do any pre-processing with `table()`. It takes raw data and does the counting internally.

Simple chart to compare counts of different values is a bar chart. You can use `geom_bar()` with raw data (uncounted). However, if you have data that is already counted, you can use `geom_col()`. See both approaches below.

##### Using `geom_bar()` for uncounted data

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(column_name = c(1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1))
ggplot(df, aes(x = column_name)) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

##### Using `geom_col()` for pre-counted data

```r
counted_data <- df$column_name |>
  table() |>
  as.data.frame()

ggplot(counted_data, aes(x = Var1, y = Freq)) +
  geom_col()
```

This produces the same graph as above.